Installed the ReportPortal in a remote machine, integrated automation framework but no result seen in reportportal ui
Installed the ReportPortal in a remote machine. When integrating selenium+cucumber6+testng automation framework with ReportPortal and executing the execution fails with below error:

com.epam.reportportal.exception.InternalReportPortalClientException: Wait for Launch start timed out

Have tried setting the attribute as rp.client.join = false, code is executed but ReportPortal UI is not updated.
Then setup the reportportal in local and when ran the same configured code it works as expected.

Mostly likely, your configuration for remote execution isn't correct. Make sure you've set properties in reportportal.properties correctly. Use this guide
